# RabbitMQ/MassTrans error message: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, message-queue, masstransit

When I try to enqueue an item into a rabbitmq queue, a guid parse exception is returned. Even if I remove all guids and replace them with string (for testing purpose), the same message occurse.

```
fail: MassTransit.Messages[0]
      S-FAULT rabbitmq://rabbitmq.rabbitmq/rs_2b94a1c9-b907-4ae6-af2b-507341cb12d9_default?bind=true fda80000-e461-fe4d-922f-08d7a2af25c9 sample.Cloud.aps.Api.Model.AddResourceRequest Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[8]
      Failed to invoke hub method 'AddResourceAsync'.
System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
   at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(Boolean overflow, String failureMessageID)
   at System.Guid.TryParseExactN(ReadOnlySpan`1 guidString, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(ReadOnlySpan`1 guidString, GuidResult& result)
   at System.Guid.Parse(String input)
   at sample.Cloud.MessageBroker.MassTransitExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<InitializeMassTransit>b__3(SendContext ctx)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.DelegateFilter`1.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.SplitFilter`2.Send(TInput context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Pipes.LastPipe`1.Send(TContext context)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Pipes.MessageSendPipe`1.GreenPipes.IPipe<MassTransit.SendContext<TOutput>>.Send(SendContext`1 context)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Pipes.SendPipe.MessagePipe`1.MassTransit.Pipeline.Pipes.SendPipe.IMessagePipe.Send[T](SendContext`1 context)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Pipes.SendPipe.MassTransit.Pipeline.ISendContextPipe.Send[T](SendContext`1 context)
   at MassTransit.Transports.SendEndpoint.EndpointSendContextPipe`1.Send(SendContext`1 context)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(ModelContext modelContext)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Transport.RabbitMqSendTransport.SendPipe`1.Send(ModelContext modelContext)
   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at sample.Cloud.aps.WebApi.Hubs.apsHub.AddResourceAsync(AddResourceRequest request) in /src/sample.Cloud.aps.WebApi/Hubs/apsHub.cs:line 90
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.ExecuteHubMethod(ObjectMethodExecutor methodExecutor, THub hub, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<Invoke>g__ExecuteInvocation|0>d.MoveNext()
Received request
```

Is there something that can be done, to debug where the issue is comming from? The error does not appear on my local rabbitmq setup, but on the azure instances.

Object that should be enquered:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add resource request
/// </summary>
public class AddResourceRequest : BaseModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the resource id
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the resource type
    /// </summary>
    public ResourceType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Code for sending the data:

```
public async Task AddResourceAsync(AddResourceRequest request)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add resource");

    var endpoint = await GetEndpointAsync(request);            
    await endpoint.Send(request);

    Console.WriteLine("...");
}

public async Task<ISendEndpoint> GetEndpointAsync(BaseModel model)
{
    return await messageBus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"queue:rs_{model.OrganizationId}_{model.Name}".ToLower()));
}
```

Comment: Any chance that model.OrganizationId could be the culprit?
I can't see the guts of your model, but perhaps it's a property that tries to parse a Guid and is failing to do so?

Comment: This are only POCOs no parsing or something else.

Comment: What is `sample.Cloud.MessageBroker.MassTransitExtensions` - there's a method in that class trying to parse a Guid that is failing. That isn't something included with MassTransit.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson your guess was right. The problem was related to the extension.